# Popen in Python 3

Tags: python, windows, pipe, popen

HERE is a code snippet from my program.

I am trying to open cmd.exe on Windows and pass commands to a separate program and capture the output and parse it WITHOUT having to load cmd.exe every time.

All the examples to do this I found where using Python 2, and there are several changes in Python 3 about PIPES, making me unsure what is going wrong.

```
#DOScmd is a list of command line parameters to type into command shell.

p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 shell=True,
                 bufsize=0)


myCall = ' '.join(DOScmd) + '\n'
p.stdin.write( bytes(myCall, 'UTF-8') )
searchLines =  p.stdout.readlines()               
print(searchLines)
```

I am calling a program bowtie.exe.  Now, bowtie.exe crashes when I do this.  I think I might be angering the I/O gods.  Any help appreciate.

Comment: *Bowties are cool!* :-) Can you post the full error output? Does `bowtie.exe` work on it's own?

Comment: there is no error output - standard window's error - "bowtie.exe has stopped working... windows is closing it."   Bowtie.exe runs from the command prompt and I have also had it work calling p = subprocess.Popen(DOScmd), where the program executes and then terminates.  The difference is I want to keep one cmd.exe open because the overhead in launching cmd.exe everytime is drastically slowing me down.

Comment: I guess the question could be asked like this: "How do I use subprocess.popen to open a program and repeatedly pass INPUT and read OUTPUT in Python 3?"

Comment: UPDATE: bowtie crashes when I close the locked up Python program, so bowtie crashing isn't the problem, rather symptom.

Comment: There are several issues in your question. Try to solve one issue at a time instead of all at once. Start by writing down *what* do you want your python script to do (not *how*). How to solve *"repeatedly pass INPUT and read OUTPUT"* depends greatly on the specific program and how do you want to interact with it specifically in your case.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to open cmd.exe on Windows and pass commands to a separate program and capture the output and parse it WITHOUT having to load cmd.exe every time.

Unless you want to run commands that are builtin to `cmd.exe` such as `dir` then you don't need to start `cmd.exe` *at all*:

```
from subprocess import check_output

for cmd in ["first.exe", "arg1", "arg2"], ["second.exe", ".."]:
    output = check_output(cmd)
    do_whatever_you_like_with(output)
```